# onclick toggle class with delay adjustment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button with `toggleClass` and `setTimeout` function, currently it is working based on the written script but I do not need delay on first click. **Hide div quickly and display with some delay**. Now both delay timings are same. Can anyone help !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(".search").toggleClass("hide");
    }, 250);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" type="button">nav</button>
<div class="search"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/f73jvtx2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never used jquery but this should work, not sure if its the cleanest solution.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".button").click(function() {
        if($(".search").hasClass("hide"))
        {
           window.setTimeout(function() {
               $(".search").toggleClass("hide");
           }, 250);
        }
   else $(".search").toggleClass("hide");
      });
    });
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" type="button">nav</button>
<div class="search"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if element is visible or hidden and then decide what to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
     if ($(".search").is(":visible")){
         $(".search").addClass("hide");
      } 
    else{
         window.setTimeout(function() {
         $(".search").toggleClass("hide");
         }, 250);
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" type="button">nav</button>
<div class="search"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using simple variable `firstClick`, initially true and then for all clicks `false`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var firstClick =true;
  $(".button").click(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    firstClick=false;
      $(".search").toggleClass("hide");
    }, firstClick?0:250);
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" type="button">nav</button>
<div class="search"><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></div>
```